# How to add admin logged in customer name in column in custom grid.?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I am adding one custom grid to my module in grid i want to add name of user who has edit or added new item. so how can I get it programatically?

here is my grid.php

```
<?php
class Maybe_Manager_Block_Adminhtml_Noticeboard_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->setId("noticeboardGrid");
                $this->setDefaultSort("id");
                $this->setDefaultDir("DESC");
                $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        }
        protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
                $collection = Mage::getModel("manager/noticeboard")->getCollection();
                $this->setCollection($collection);
                return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
        protected function _prepareColumns()
        {
                $this->addColumn("id", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("manager")->__("ID"),
                "align" =>"right",
                "width" => "50px",
                "type" => "number",
                "index" => "id",
                ));
                $this->addColumn("create_at", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("manager")->__("Create At"),
                "index" => "create_at",
                ));
                $this->addColumn("created_by", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("manager")->__("Created By"),
                "index" => "created_by",
                ));
                $this->addColumn("college_list", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("manager")->__("Colleges"),
                "index" => "college_list",
                ));
                $this->addColumn("city_list", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("manager")->__("Cities"),
                "index" => "city_list",
                ));
                $this->addColumn('action_edit', array(
                'header'   => $this->helper('manager')->__('Action'),
                'width'    => 15,
                'sortable' => false,
                'filter'   => false,
                'type'     => 'action',
                'actions'  => array(
                                    array(
                                        'url'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/*/edit'),
                                        'caption' => $this->helper('manager')->__('Edit'),
                                    ),
                                    )
                ));

            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV')); 
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel'));

                return parent::_prepareColumns();
        }

        public function getRowUrl($row)
        {
               return $this->getUrl("*/*/edit", array("id" => $row->getId()));
        }
        protected function _prepareMassaction()
        {
            $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('ids');
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(true);
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('remove_noticeboard', array(
                     'label'=> Mage::helper('manager')->__('Remove Noticeboard'),
                     'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/adminhtml_noticeboard/massRemove'),
                     'confirm' => Mage::helper('manager')->__('Are you sure?')
                ));
            return $this;
        }
```